# What does the notation $\operatorname{Mat}_{b'}^bf$ represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

This is a notation that my professor uses, that I haven't been able to find anywhere else. It has to do with representative matrices for a certain transformation from one basis to the other, I believe, but I'm still not sure as to what it's supposed to represent. Does anyone know? Thanks.

I should have put this down before, but here is what my notes say:

> Let $f: E_b \to F_{b'}$ and $B = \{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n\}$, then $ \operatorname{Mat}_{b'}^b f = [f(e_1) \; f(e_2) \; \cdots \; f(e_n)] \, B^{\,'}$

Comment: Perhaps the matrix representation of a linear transformation $f$ with respect to bases $b$ (codomain) and $b'$ (domain).

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thanks for the response. What does that really even mean though? Is it just a transformation that takes a vector thats in base B and returns a vector that's in base B'?

Comment: You're getting the idea, though your vocab isn't accurate.  A basis $B$ is finite, so it's not likely that a vector lies in $B$.  I *guess* it means the matrix takes $\large [v]_{B'}$ to $[Tv]_B$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I've added some relevant info that I should have added before; would you mind taking a look at it?

Comment: How is $B$ typeset in your notes?  I've tried to improve MathJax, but it's possible that my [edit] changes the meaning of your question.  Plz check.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Sorry, what do you mean by typeset?

Comment: I mean "to render something in LaTeX"

Comment: @GNUSupporter I'm sure you know this, but B was meant to be a basis of E. Usually, in class, we define those around parentheses; is this what you're asking about? For example, it's written as $B = (e_1, ..., e_n)$ in my notes.

Comment: OK.  I'm using {} to emphasize that it's a finite *set* of basis vectors, but I think many authors are using ().  The main reason that I'm asking you to verify my edit is the rightmost $B^{\,'}$.  I'm not sure how it's shown in your notes.  It's normal font $B^{\,'}$, subscript $_{B^{\,'}}$ or superscript $^{B^{\,'}}$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Oooh, I see. In my notes, the rightmost $B'$ actually seems to be in normal font, which I'm assuming is meant to denote multiplication with the vector on its left?

Comment: I see why it's in normal font.  First you have $[v]_{B^{\,'}}$.  You left multiply in to get $B' [v]_{B^{\,'}} = [v]_{\rm std}$.  Then you left multiply it with $[f(e_1) \; f(e_2) \; \cdots \; f(e_n)]$ to get $[f(v)]_{\rm std}$.  Unless $B$ is the standard basis, I think a $B^{-1}$ is missing here since it's w.r.t. $B$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter That's strange; there's no mention of $B^{-1}$ in the notes. However, it does say that $[f(x)]_{B'} = \operatorname{Mat}_{b'}^bf * [x]_B$. I'm sorry if I'm being dense, but I really am so lost here.

Comment: Was your notes taken during lecture?  Otherwise, you should be able to find the text which defines $\rm Mat_{b'}^b$.  From the equation in your last comment (coordinates w.r.t $B$ in, coordinates w.r.t $B'$ out), it seems that I inverted the role of $b$ and $b'$.